# String length in files

Tags: c

I'm trying to create a program where it gets some text from any file and codes every character, except spaces, with the underscore `'_'`.

For example, let's say we have the words `"name"` and `"code"` in 2 separate lines in a file. The program will eventually do this:

```
_ _ _ _ 
_ _ _ _
```

The thing is that when I run the code the 1st line is printed with one extra underscore but the last line is printed normally. The code is:

```
while(1)
{
    if(fgets(str, 100, fp) == NULL)
        break;
    for(i=0; i<strlen(str); i++)
    {
        if(str[i] != ' ')
        {
            printf("%c ", '_');
        }
        else
            printf(" ");
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Please [edit]  your question and post a [mcve]. Also show an example of input and expected output.

Comment: What if instead of `if(str[i] != ' ')` you put `if(isprint(str[i]));`? I suspect that you are also transforming some other whitespace character like a line break into an underscore. `isprint` is from `<ctype.h>` IIRC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because `fgets` retains the newline character from the end of each line in the file, but the last line does not contain one. The code does not test for whitespace characters, only an *actual* space. You can remove the newline with

```
str [ strcspn(str, "\r\n") ] = '\0';
```